# GCP Compute Engine Ubuntu VM instance password

Tags: ubuntu, cloud, google

I have a projected hosted on a virtual machine instance (with ubuntu onboard)
which runs in GCP-Compute Engine.

When I want to elevate my priveleges typing "sudo -i", ubuntu asks me a passoword, what kind of password does google cloud want?), I tried my gcp account's password and it does not work hope you can help with some ideas on this

[example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Acyv.png)

Best regards,

Comment: `sudo` usually needs _your_ accounts' password. Why do you use `sudo -i` though?

Comment: sudo -i to use root priveleges

Comment: I edited the sudoers file, trying to add a new user, after this I lost the ability to use "sudo", also observed that the string which were before printed like (Connected, host fingerprint: ssh-rs .....) is missing now

Comment: `sudo` means `su do`, which in most cases means: `superuser/root do`. You - normally - don't need the `-i` switch, you use it in conjunction with your needed command, e. g.: `sudo apt-get update`, or whatever. How did you add your user to sudoers?

Comment: I typed "sudo visudo", and added  after admin line, if I rembmer correctly I've added something like "newName ALL=(ALL:ALL)ALL".

Comment: Now any command that requires "sudo" is asking me to type the psw

Comment: Do you use GoogleCloudShell? Doesn't `sudo` work with your own users password? You obviously broke your sudoers file (and shouldn't have to edit in manually, anyway).

Comment: ah I thought it could be caused by expired ssh but no, I am using putty for the connection to the instance, is it possible somehow to fix the sudoer file?

Answer (score 0):

## The Short answer

- You killed your `/etc/sudoers`
- Verify the Integrity´with `visudo -c`

  - if everything is ok it will give you an output like

    ```sh
    root@f00bar:/# visudo -c
    /etc/sudoers: parsed OK
    /etc/sudoers.d/README: parsed OK
    ```

## The Long Answer:

### Default Sudo File

(In case you want to overwrite your one)

```
## Default Debian `/etc/sudoers`

#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

### Use "visudo"

### Manpage `visudo`

> visudo edits the sudoers file in a safe fashion, analogous to vipw(8).
>
> visudo locks the sudoers file against multiple simultaneous edits, provides basic sanity checks, and checks for parse errors.
>
> If the sudoers file is currently being edited you will receive a message to try again later.
>
> visudo parses the sudoers file after editing and will not save the changes if there is a syntax error.  Upon finding an error,
> visudo will print a message stating the line number(s) where the error occurred and the user will receive the “What now?” prompt.
> At this point the user may enter ‘e’ to re-edit the sudoers file, ‘x’ to exit without saving the changes, or ‘Q’ to quit and save changes.
>
> The ‘Q’ option should be used with extreme caution because if visudo believes there to be a parse error, so will sudo and no one will be able to run sudo again until the error is fixed.
>
> If ‘e’ is typed to edit the sudoers file after a parse error has been detected, the cursor will be placed on the line where the error occurred (if the editor supports this feature).

#### Howto get Password-Less Sudo User?

- YOUR_USERNAME_HERE ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

#### Howto get Password-Less Sudo Group?

- %YOUR_GROUPNAME_HERE ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

  - The Difference is, users are without and User-Groups with a Percent written in front of them.

## Conclusion

Dont edit the sudo file on your own, if you are unfamilar with the Syntax.